# How to stop the subscription to "/parameter_events" that is automatically created in each node

Tags: ros, ros2, node, rclcpp, ros-iron

I have been able to stop the publisher to the topic (`/parameter_events`) by setting `start_parameter_event_publisher` in `NodeOptions` to `false`. Is there a way to stop the subscriber?

Answer (score 0):

A node should not have a default subscriber for `/parameter_events`: the programmer of the node chooses to either add that subscription, or not.

However, currently a subscriber is created [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/411dbe8212dd753ee60871f8605d0a8beaae5e37/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/time_source.cpp#L280-L285).

There's is a ['TODO' remark](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/411dbe8212dd753ee60871f8605d0a8beaae5e37/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/time_source.cpp#L280) about this in the code, which references [this github issue](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/609). I left a remark to [reopen that issue](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/609#issuecomment-1809775436).

So as of yet, to disable the subscription, I don't see another option than to change it in the code and compile `rclcpp` from source. Removing above mentioned lines effectively ensures that the subscription is no longer made (I tested it). However, based on a quick look at the [callback function](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/411dbe8212dd753ee60871f8605d0a8beaae5e37/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/time_source.cpp#L479), I assume that this  breaks the `use_sim_time` parameter functionality.

Comment: I think that's basically what I am asking. I am not sure I have found an option in NodeOptions to stop it. (I have disabled parameters in general)

Comment: If it is about a specific node that you are using, post a reference to that node and I can have a look. Or if you experience that nodes which you wrote subscribe to `/parameter_events` without you explicitly creating such a subscription in that node, post a minimal example, as I don't think that that should happen.

Comment: The minimal publisher and minimal subscriber example in ROS 2 documentation is what I am working with

Comment: You are correct, I changed my answer.